# Error al ejecutar script, fallo al cargar DLL

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Estoy tratando de aplicar una de mis primeras aplicaciones en Qt5 con Python 3.5.2:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

def window():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.Qwidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

Pero me genera el siguiente error:

> from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: No se encontró el proceso especificado

Comment: Jsierra tenemos un problema... XD. El problema es que el error se puede deber a mil cosas. ¿Cómo has instalado PyQt? ¿Son el intérprete y tu versión de PyQt para la misma arquitectura (32/64 bits)? ¿Usas anaconda o entornos virtuales? ¿Se encuentra la carpeta PyQt5 en `\Lib\site-packages` dentro del directorio de instalación de Python? En teoría esas dlls deberian estar en `Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin` si mal no recuerdo (no tengo Windows a mano ahora). El error por desgracia puede deberse a muchas cosas, a mi me pasó una vez con Qt4, si mal no recuerdo, y era un tema de permisos.

Comment: si exactamente esta instalado en la direccion \Lib\site-packages dentro del directorio de instalación de Python? En teoría esas dlls deberian estar en Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin lo desintale y le volvi a instalar la ultima version pero ya me apaerece otro error:  from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
ImportError: No module named 'sip'

Comment: cargue la ultima version con errores corregidos para python 3.5 y 3.6?

Comment: y sale ese otro error

Comment: Esto no debe causar el error que primario  que muestras, pero tienes un error tipográfico en  `w = QtWidgets.Qwidget()`, debe ser `w = QtWidgets.QWidget()`. Esto no tiene nada que ver con tu error que se produce al importar, pero que causará un `unhandled AttributeError`.

Comment: hice el cambio a QWidget() pero aparece el error :                                   
 from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
ImportError: No module named 'sip'

Comment: print (sys.path)
['C:\\Python35\\BORRADORES', 'C:\\Python35\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Python35\\python35.zip', 'C:\\Python35\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python35\\lib', 'C:\\Python35', 'C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']

Comment: sera que python no encuentra a pyqt5

Comment: ese es el path de su ubicacion

Comment: No lo creo, en ese caso el error haría referencia directa a PyQt (`ImportError: No module named PyQt5`). El problema es que no encuentra [SIP](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download), que es una de las dependencias de PyQt. Dependiendo como instalaras PyQt, se debería, o no, haber resuelto el tema de las dependencias. Intenta instalar sip : `py -3.5 -m pip install sip`

Comment: ya lo instale pero sigue igual

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62426/discussion-between-fjsevilla-and-jsierra2017).